# iGoogle platform for intranet page

Tags: java, compatibility, platform, google-gadget, igoogle

Does it exists a platform or container capable of running google gadgets written for iGoogle.
Basicly what I want is to have my private "iGoogle" intranet page.

I found out that LifeRay, Sun Java System Portal Server, Weblogic Portal Server and JBoss Portal Server should be capable of running google gadgets and i'd like to know if this is true.
Are this implementations compatible with those of an iGoogle ?

Many thanks and best regards to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shindig is opensource implementation of iGoogle container (gadgets api and open social api).

Beside shindig you can use GateIn, Jboss or liferay portal. At the end we choose GateIn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the platforms you mention, but you can create private gadgets for use on a Google Apps Google Sites Start Page.  You create the gadgets, upload them to Google using FSCT, and use the Google Secure Data Connector to get to your data.